# Why does my datagrid not display my input data?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been trying to work this out and Google this for a long time and can't find a solution. I have created an SQL table / database , a user inputs data into input fields I have created, then a save button is pressed to save it to the database. I have then on another tab bound a data grid to my table, but upon clicking the save button on another tab, the grid does not display any results upon returning to that tab, am I doing something wrong here or do I have to write code to refresh? Below is my code for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="employeeDetailsTableDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="295,160,26,85" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" SelectionChanged="employeeDetailsTableDataGrid_SelectionChanged" FontFamily="Arial">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="employeeIDColumn" Binding="{Binding EmployeeID}" Header="Employee ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="forenameColumn" Binding="{Binding Forename}" Header="Forename" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="surnameColumn" Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Surname" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dOBColumn" Header="DOB" Width="SizeToHeader">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DOB, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailAddressColumn" Binding="{Binding EmailAddress}" Header="Email Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="countryColumn" Binding="{Binding Country}" Header="Country" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cityColumn" Binding="{Binding City}" Header="City" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="postcodeColumn" Binding="{Binding Postcode}" Header="Postcode" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="skill1Column" Binding="{Binding Skill1}" Header="Skill 1" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="skill2Column" Binding="{Binding Skill2}" Header="Skill 2" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="skill3Column" Binding="{Binding Skill3}" Header="Skill 3" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="job1Column" Binding="{Binding Job1}" Header="Job 1" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="job2Column" Binding="{Binding Job2}" Header="Job 2" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="job3Column" Binding="{Binding Job3}" Header="Job 3" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="employeeAvailabilityColumn" Binding="{Binding EmployeeAvailability}" Header="Employee Availability" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you binding it to a ViewModel? typically my `ItemsSource` looks like this: `ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionName}"`

Comment: Oh so would I change that to my table name?

Comment: Previously binding was set to: ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: Update binding to the property that has the results. If that is bound make sure you raise the property changed event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` is updated to the property name or, for the property that is binded here, you should raise the PropertyChangedEventHandler with that property name so that xaml gets notification that change has occurred and thus your data grid should refresh.

For now it seems like your `ItemsSource` is binded to what ever object it is inheriting. Could be the view model.
On how to set property name in Binding: `ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyName}"`

Another possible solution could be to refresh your grid `grid.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: Would the property be the actual table in the DB? If so it doesn't allow for me to type the full table only to bind to particular columns etc.

Comment: @AaronG no the property will not be the actual table in the DB. it can be Table.ColumnName. It needs to be property in the DataContext of the datagridview. Listen to DataGridView's datacontext changed and see what type of object is getting associated. From that object choose the property that you want to bind. DataType of the property can be a Datatable.